# Encountering this error /usr/bin/ld: final link failed: No space left on device

Tags: centos, opensource-projects

**/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: No space left on device** is the error coming when I'm trying to complie Open Source code project

I have about 7GB free space over the Disk so I think that cannot be the cause of the issue.

I have read some where, that if source file is too big the linker error like this can be encountered; this can be true because source file is really huge.
If the linker is giving an error due to file size then what can be done to solve the problem.

Comment: And the project name is?..  You might have better luck checking the project's FAQ.

Comment: Copy-paste the full compilation log, so we can see exactly where you're getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

The linker needs to store temporary files. Guess: the temporary directory (often `/tmp`) is full. Remedy: clean up `/tmp`, make `/tmp` bigger, or use a different temporary directory (`export TMPDIR=/path/to/directory/with/`).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check :

1. What filesystem do you have. e.g. FAT32 does not allow more than 2GB files.
2. Is there i-node available, `df -i`. You can have multiple files that are smaller than the block size, then you have free space but cannot create more file since I-node list is full.

On both cases you may have to reformat to a new type of partition allowing bigger files and/or more inodes.

Comment: so M'vy what's best file partition which has maximum number of nodes so that my problem can be solved

Comment: Did you tested the `df -i` first?

Comment: its showing something like this 1146880-INodes  138156-IUsed 1008724-IFree can this help

Comment: So it has free inodes.

Comment: okay that means what can be next possibility then M'vy

Comment: Well I'm not omniscient, try to make more diagnostic. Is there a partition with 0 free space, or 0 i-nodes. It would be better to know if the problem is really the size of some file before reformatting. You don't want to loose your data.

Comment: Can it be something to do with the ld configuration. I'm just thinking could the problem be with some other reason.